# TriggerType Expression Blend 4

Tags: expression-blend, eventtrigger, expression-blend-4

I was wondering if it is possible to assign an eventtrigger to a source outside the current artboard.

Example: I have a text box that I want to slide out of one content presenter into another when a button is selected. I have it set up so the box slides out of one and I need to bind the box to slide into the new content presenter when the previous trigger was selected.

Answer (score 1):

What you described sounds an awful lot like the FluidMoveBehavior from the Blend SDK.  It's a more advanced Blend concept, but it's quite snazzy and should provide a nice animation as your move your control from one container to another.  [Here's a quick tutorial on it.](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/fluidui/fluidmovemasterdetail.aspx)

Comment: @Mike_Post Thanks for the answer, but it isn't exactly what I am shooting for. I have a single screen with two, seperate content controllers. I am looking to move a text box that is visible from one content controller to a seperate content controller with the click of a button(toggle, check, etc.)